# connect to firebird via ODBC: x32 vs x64

Tags: odbc, 64-bit, firebird, 32bit-64bit, firebird-3.0

I've installed on Win10 x64 latest firebird x64 3.0 and created database under it. I've also installed both x32 and x64 ODBC drivers. Now i've created System DSN connection via x64 driver against fbclient.dll and successfully tested it.

After that i've created x32 ODBC system DSN connection via different clients:
1) In case of using WOW64\fbclient.dll i obtained next error:

---

### Firebird ODBC Setup

Connection failed!
Error loading plugin Engine12

### Module C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_3_0\plugins/Engine12 exists but can not be loaded

### OK

2) In case of using 'System32\gds32.dll' i've obtained

---

### Firebird ODBC Setup

Connection failed!

### File Database is not found

### OK

How do i connect to such an instance via x32?

Comment: You might want to include the exact configuration of your DSNs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is - given the error - that the way you configured your DSN means that you are using embedded mode (you probably did not include a host name in your connection). If you want to use 32 bit embedded mode, then you must have a 32 bit engine12.dll, but currently you have a 64 bit engine12.dll, which can't be loaded in a 32 bit process.

You must either connect to your Firebird server install (through localhost), or install 32 bit Firebird so that you have a 32 bit engine12.dll.